# load RSS in HTML webpage

Tags: html, rss

I'm new to coding. I'm trying new things to learn better coding techniques.

Right now I'm trying to create a web page which would load an RSS news feed from fifa.com in my page but I don't know how to make it work.

Here is a reference to the RSS newsfeed I'd like to retrieve:

http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/rss.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using one of the following JQuery plug-in:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rss

Learning JQuery is an important skill to develop.

Comment: or [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) or [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)...